# Optimizing perceived load time for social sharing widgets on a page?

Tags: javascript, load-time

I have placed the facebook "like" and some other social bookmarking websites link on my blog, such as Google Buzz, Digg, Twitter, etc.

I  just noticed that it takes a while to load my blog page as it need to load the data from the social networking sites (such as number of likes etc).

How can I place the links efficiently so that first my blog content loads, and meanwhile it loads data from these websites -- in other words, these sharing widgets should not hang my blog page while waiting for data from external sites?

Answer (score 2):

Here you will find some useful information:
http://www.w3-edge.com/weblog/2011/02/optimize-social-media-button-performance/

It explain how to speed-up things with various social buttons!

It's an article of Frederic Townsend, of W3 Total Cache plugin for Wordpress. Very interisting reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some javascript to execute on document ready to inject the code you need. If you have placeholders for your widgets, then you can start filling them after your page has loaded.